# stretch the background image to component above

Tags: css

I have to components one above the other. I would like to stretch the bg image from the lower one to the upper one. I set the background of the upper one as transparent but I cannot figure out what to do to stretch the image above the component in the second one. I've got

```
display: block;
background-image: url(${background});
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% -50%;
```

but the size property is invalid and any positive value doesn't seen to do what I would like it to do. Could you help?

Comment: You can not stretch the background of an element outside of the dimensions of that element, duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you are going for without a proper link, but I think you could achieve this by having the second component with a negative `margin-top`, and equivalent `padding-top`.

HTML:

```
<div class="comp-a">
    I am the first component
</div>
<div class="comp-b">
    I am the second. I control the background!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.comp-a {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
.comp-b {
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrsapyqv/